# Jquery .find after render html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
tblBody = $('#tbody');
tblBody.html(rowsStr.join(''));

var lines = tblBody.find("tr");
```

The **rowsStr** is a Array with strings that form tr and td tags.

Sometimes the **tblBody.find("tr")** returns empty and somtimes returns with tr elements.
After press F5, it work and sometimes not work, for the same case.

I think sometimes the browser can´t load the **tblBody.html(rowsStr.join(''))** in time to execute the **find** function.

In the end of the process I have a complete table with tr's and td's (with inputs, labels,...).

Can anybody help?

Tks

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: What you are describing shouldn't be possible. A jsfiddle or jsBin reproducing the problem is the next step in solving this problem.

Comment: if the string isn't valid html...missing closing tags, extra closing tags , invalid child nesting etc...that can cause unexpected behavior

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The script is inside a include .js document and is executed right after the .js load.
My #tblbody element is after the execution function. Sometimes its works, because the cache and sometimes not because the #tblbody element does not loaded yet.

```
<script language="javascript" src="utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
.
.
.
<table>
    <tbody id="tblbody"><tbody>
</table>
```

Tks to all.

Answer (score -2):

Try to put the hole code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*code here */ });
```